# angular js success response $scope variable another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to access angular js success response $scope variable another function

```
$scope.mydoc = function() {
  var params = {
    tribe_id: $scope.parentCtrl.id
  };
  dealRoomApiService.getOfflineLoanDocs(params)
    .then(function(resp) {
      $scope.docList = resp.data;
    }, function(error) {
      toastr.error(error.data.detail); //Show a toast notification
    });
  }
```

in above function  **`$scope.docList`** i want to access another below function

```
$scope.myDoc = function(doc, index) {
      console.log("Test....",$scope.docList);

    };
```

Comment: That will be available. No issues in the current code

Comment: @Nitheesh,  Notice `dealRoomApiService.getOfflineLoanDocs` must be  aync

Comment: $scope is available everywhere across the controller, so you should be able to access it, however, if you need to pass it on to another route use $rootScope instead.

Comment: I got only undifend

Comment: When `$scope.mydoc` and `$scope.myDoc` functions are invoked?

Comment: @Satpal Good question, it would then mean the answer should be;

$scope.myDoc = function(doc, index) {
      $scope.mydoc();
      console.log("Test....",$scope.docList);

    };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think `dealRoomApiService.getOfflineLoanDocs` is an asynchronous function. This should work.

```
dealRoomApiService.getOfflineLoanDocs(params)
.then(function(resp) {
  $scope.docList = resp.data;
  $scope.myDoc();
}, function(error) {
  toastr.error(error.data.detail); //Show a toast notification
});
```